# Неверная кодировка для aiohttp

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Я обращаюсь клиентом aiohttp к сайту, и у меня вылетает исключение

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 30, in check_eng
text = await resp.text()
File "C:\python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 713, in text
return self._content.decode(encoding, errors=errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0
        in position 43381: invalid continuation byte
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<check_eng() done, defined at main.py:15> 
        exception=LookupError('unknown encoding: cp-1251',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 30, in check_eng
text = await resp.text()
File "C:\python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 713, in text
return self._content.decode(encoding, errors=errors)
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp-1251
```

Если я правильно понял, то это связяно с тем, что в html сайта указана невалидная кодировка, подскажите как исправить это

Comment: Код свой покажите.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего будет пропатчить питон для этого сайта. Это надо добавить до импорта остальных модулей.

```
import encodings
encodings.aliases.aliases['cp_1251'] = 'cp1251'
```

На основе ответа с большого SO
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064191/2101808